How can i customize odoo 17 views, like colors, modify the base icons
I want to customize the odoo 17 base theme, to create a customized environment, is there any documentation about it? cause in the odoo documentation there is no info about it.
I donwloaded anoter theme and got the code, but i really want to know the basics and where those things come from.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Below are the steps to customize base icons:
Customize odoo 17 views - Base icons
In Odoo site,

Activate the developer mode - To enable developer mode, go to Settings and click on the “Activate Developer Mode” option at the bottom of the page.
Navigate to Settings -> Technical -> User Interface -> Menu items
Locate and access the menu where the icon needs to be updated.
Click on edit button in “Web Icon Image” Field and upload new Icon.
Save and Refresh page.

In Code,

Open the base module which the icon has to be changed.
Navigate to static -> description.
Replace the icon.png with another icon.
Note : Keep file name as “icon.png”.Don't change the filename.

Below is one of the way to customize themes:
Customize the theme using third-party module.
Module Name : MuK Backend Theme

Install Muk Backend Theme Module from odoo app store.
Add modules in odoo base code.
Activate the module in odoo page and theme will automatically change once the module is loaded

For Customizing colours:

Navigate to Settings -> General Settings page.
Search “Backend Theme”.

